# How to split specified network into subnets using Python

Tags: python, network-programming, divide, subnet

I've been working on this question, but can't find a clearance.

I have a Python script which should get two arguments - network/CIDR & a number. The script should divide specified network to a number of parts, subnets, and show parameters of those subnets, like network address, broadcast, number of hosts.

Actually, my current code state is [here](https://github.com/eyablokov/subnet-divider/blob/master/subnet-divider.py), on GitHub.

The reason I'm asking is there are other topic on Stack Overflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864268/splitting-a-network-into-subnets-of-multiple-prefixes), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420588/subnetting-to-split-network-into-smaller-networks) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191608/how-to-divide-a-network-into-eleven-subnets). But all of them have prefixes. And my point is, for example, `./subnet-divider.py 200.100.33.65/26 3`, so I should divide it into 3 subnets. Or `./subnet-divider.py 200.100.33.65/26 9`. So this is a different point, although slightly similar to discussed.

I crossed around both modules - [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ipaddress.html) and [netaddr](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). Both are similar. There are generators for subnetting, but they have arguments like `prefix`, required, and `count`, which is good.

```
In [22]: s.get_subnet(27, count=3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5864cbfc587d> in <module>()
----> 1 s.get_subnet(27, count=3)

/home/simple/Projects/subnet-divider/ip_splitter.py in get_subnet(self, prefix, count)
     14         """ . """

     15         for ip_network in self.get_available_ranges():
---> 16             subnets = list(ip_network.subnet(prefix, count=count))
     17             if not subnets:
     18                 continue

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netaddr/ip/__init__.py in subnet(self, prefixlen, count, fmt)
   1269 
   1270         if not 1 <= count <= max_subnets:
-> 1271             raise ValueError('count outside of current IP subnet boundary!')
   1272 
   1273         base_subnet = self._module.int_to_str(self.first)

ValueError: count outside of current IP subnet boundary!
```

Of course, that' correct.

So, How can I divide? To do it flexible, I don't need a prefix, but the script should be able to divide incoming network onto specified subnets, 3, 7, 10, etc to the max.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this case for myself. Just to divide.

[This message](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12693/5546) helped. So, we have a pair & number to divide. We can calculate prefix length of subnets.

The code is in repo.